# rsync between two machines with ssh and MFA without password

Tags: rsync

I have two machines that are accessible with ssh + MFA. I need to rsync regularly between these two but would like to avoid doing MFA each time. Setting up a keypair is not an option since MFA will not allow it.

I tried a few forms of ssh tunneling but no luck as ultimately it is ssh that does the transfer which invokes the authentication mechanism. The direction of rsync doesn't matter as both machines are accessible with MFA. I do not have admin access on either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You do not have admin access, it is the problem. You can create a long life ssh connection and tunnelling, but it isn't a good idea. Ask the administrators.

Comment: @K-att- I can create ssh tunnel but is it possible to tell rsync to reuse the existing ssh connection rather than start a new one?

Comment: Use the sshfs then. Hint: https://gist.github.com/mfellner/5743990